# Firebase notification not receiving when firebasemessage service not initilized

Tags: android, firebase

Actually, I am starting firebase message service depends on app requirement. Before starting firebase message service programmatically I am sending one notification it is not receiving but after when I start firebase message service programmatically and sends notification this one also not receiving. I do not understand why this is happening.

```
 Logging event (FE): notification_receive(_nr), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=fcm, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2530909691907984364}]
   Logging event (FE): notification_foreground(_nf), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=fcm, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=2530909691907984364}]

I am stopping service like this

     ComponentName componentName3 = new ComponentName(context, FirebasefcmService.class);
                context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName3,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: are you using Oreo device for testing?

Comment: yes in oreo device i am testing

Answer (score 0):

**For Firebase push notification on Oreo devices**

**1. Write this meta-data in Manifest File**

```html
<service android:name=".CustomFirebaseMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    <action android:name=".SplashActivity" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
    android:exported="false" />
    
<meta-data       
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

**2. For Register Device to Push Notification**

```html
public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
    // abbreviated tag name
    private static final String TAG = RegistrationIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    private String android_id;
    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }
    String token;
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Make a call to Instance API

        FirebaseInstanceId instanceID = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance();

        
        //String senderId = getResources().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId);

        // request token that will be used by the server to send push notifications
        token = instanceID.getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Registration Token: " + token);
    }
}
```

**3. Refresh Device Token Service class to register new token to firebase**

```html
public class CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**4. For receive push notification in foreground**

```html
public class CustomFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = CustomFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private int notificationID = 100;
    private int numMessages = 0;
    String title, message, image;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
            image = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            image = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
        }

        displayNotification(getApplicationContext(),title,message,image);

    }

    protected void displayNotification(Context context, String PUSH_TITLE, String PUSH_MSG, String PUSH_IMAGE) {
        Log.i("Start", "notification");

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

       /* Invoking the default notification service */
        NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(PUSH_TITLE);
        mBuilder.setContentText(PUSH_MSG);
        mBuilder.setTicker("Message from "+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
        mBuilder.setLargeIcon(icon);
        /* Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives */
        mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);
        System.out.println("Push image:"+PUSH_IMAGE);
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle notiStyle = new
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        notiStyle.setBigContentTitle(PUSH_TITLE);
        notiStyle.bigText(PUSH_MSG);
        mBuilder.setStyle(notiStyle);
        /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(SplashActivity.class);

        /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated.
            String CHANNEL_ID = getResources().getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);// The id of the channel.
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);// The user-visible name of the channel.
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mChannel.setSound(null, null);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            mBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }
       /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am not getting message in onmessagereceived

Comment: is firebase configured well?

Comment: yes everything configured properly but when i am in background it is working fine but in foreground it is not coming into onmessagereceived

Comment: if device is in background push notification is working fine but if device is in foreground it is not receiving

Comment: check CustomFirebaseMessagingService Class its for receive push while app in foreground
and check your manifest

Comment: whatever code you have written same code i have written but problem is i am  enabling firebase service programatically. In manifest firebase service is in disabled state

Comment: while service is in disabled state i have sent notification it didn't receive but when i enable service programatically still it is not receiving in foreground

Comment: <service android:name=".CustomFirebaseMessagingService">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    <action android:name=".SplashActivity" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>

Comment: write this service tag in manifest it will call CustomFirebaseMessagingService when push notification receive (MESSAGING_EVENT happens)

Comment: when i put debug it is coming to android FirebaseMessageService class but it is not delivering to onmessagereceived

Comment: are you sending push from firebase console?

Comment: comment your code for stop service and reinstall app

Comment: if i use stop service it is working fine but programatically component settings should enable it

Comment: don't stop service let it run. let it run

Comment: my requirement i will start and stop service based on client options

Comment: give settings for disable push notification. and store in saved pref and check pref in CustomFirebaseMessagingService